# Javascript: Regex to capture white space and special characters EXCEPT hyphens within words

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently using `/[\W]+/g` gets me all non-word characters, which is what I want.

However, I'd like to omit hyphens, when they are not surrounded by spaces (that is, when they're used as joining words).

Examples:

```
 var test = [
    'e-mail', // Nothing  shouldn't be captured
    'e-commerce is great.', // Spaces and full stop should be captured
    'He - yes he - went', // Dashes and white space should be captured
    'He&-you, me-him' // &-, and the whitespace should be captured while the dash in me-him should not
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using
`([\W]-|-[\W]|[^\w-])+`

Negations in regex are fiddly, often you have to use lookaheads to solve the problem, but here there was a simple fix. Rather than matching all non-word characters (`[\W]`), I matched anything that was not a word character or a hyphen (`[^\w-]`), and then added in the special case of when a hyphen was *not* surrounded by characters (`[\W]-` and `-[\W]`). I had to put the hyphen captures first, otherwise the non-word, non-hyphen capture will match the two spaces or special characters and the next part would fail to pick up the hyphen.

Comment: That's right on the money, check out this [refiddle](http://refiddle.com/refiddles/55eeed1975622d484f700000) that I just replaced the `[[:space:]]` with a `\s`, looks like it fits the criteria.

Comment: Sorry, I have just updated it with `\s` instead of [:space:].